# Why is 'as' keyword needed to access functionality when already checked with 'is' keyword?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Recently I started making more use of interfaces and inheritance, and I try to pass those as parameters into functions to make my code more flexible.
But what really annoys me when I use generic functions is that I always have to use the keywords `is` and `as` together.
For example:

```
interface Imail
{
   string GetBody();
   string GetSubject();
}

interface IAttachment
{
   IEnumerable<Attachment> GetAttachments();
}

public MailMessage GetMail<T>(T mailObject) where T: Imail
{
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   mail.Subject = mailObject.GetSubject();
   mail.Body = mailObject.GetBody();

   if (mailObject is IAttachment)
      foreach (var att in (mailObject as IAttachment).GetAttachments())
          mail.Attachments.Add(att);

   return mail;
}
```

This certainly doesn't make the code more readable, and is just not needed in my opinion. Why can't I just use `mailObject.GetAttachments()` after I check if it implements the interface (or baseclass for that matter) with `is`? Or is it possible and am I just missing something? Please enlighten me with your wisdom SO senpais!

Comment: just imagine if you do check: `if (mailObject is IAttachment && mailObject is ISomethingElse)` and both `IAttachment` and `ISomethingElse` have method `GetAttachments` with different meaning. compiler first and then fellow programmers will go mad. so it is a good language design decision to limit power of `is` operator

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `is` is you just want to test if an object implements an interface.
- Use `as` when you want to both test if an object implements an interface and you also want to type the reference with the interface.

This code:

```
if (mailObject is IAttachment)
      foreach (var att in (mailObject as IAttachment).GetAttachments())
          mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```

...should look as follows:

```
IAttachment attachment = mailObject as IAttachment;

if(attachment != null) 
    foreach (var att in attachment.GetAttachments())
         mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```

Keep in mind `is` operator has to perform the cast internally to test that the whole reference implements your interface. That is, **your code will be more efficient if you avoid the double cast for the `is` and later `as` operators**.

Comment: Didn't know `as` also did the same check as `is`, thanks!

Comment: I hope it will be implemented differently in C#7 like Jon said

Comment: For your edit, if I understand correctly both `is` and `as` do the same internally but `is` throws away the cast and returns a bool instead?

Comment: I doubt that there is any appreciable difference versus the two approaches. Both `is` and `as` are very fast operations. I would go for readability on this.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah... BTW, in terms of readability efficiency, avoiding `is` on this case should help, shouldn't it? Efficiency has to do with a lot of aspects: performance, readability, productivity...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I just checked the IL and it appears the there is more code for the `as`/`!= null` version than the `is`/`as` version.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's curious, isn't it? BTW, sometimes I try to address issues from the high level point of view: the code with as is still more readable than checking with `is` and then casting, or maybe it's just my opinion

Comment: @Enigmativity And... anyway we should make a perf test, because not always less or more code lines is means more performance

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I've added an answer that shows the IL. Both `is` and `as` are implemented with a rather large `isinst` instruction. But, you're right, we have to actually measure performance to know which is truly faster.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is because you cannot mutate the type of a variable in C#, you can only introduce new variables. Your mailObject has the type T and will continue to have that type, no matter what you do with it. Use the `as` keyword to type-check and introduce a new variable at the same time:

```
var newType = obj as ISomething;
if(newType != null)
{
    //newType is still a reference to obj, but is now of type ISomething.
}
```

Note: C#7 might be implementing pattern matching, with which such checks might look like this:

```
switch(mailObject)
{
    case IAttachment attachment:
       foreach (var att in attachment.GetAttachments())
           mail.Attachments.Add(att);
       break;
    // other cases
}
```

Comment: That would be great as I need to check for multiple interfaces in my program :)

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I just use mailObject.GetAttachments() after I check if it implements the interface (or baseclass for that matter) with is?

Because the compile-time type of the `mailObject` variable is still just `T`.

Note that currently you're performing the dynamic type check twice - a generally preferred approach is:

```
var attachment = mailObject as IAttachment;
if (attachment != null)
{
    foreach (var att in attachment.GetAttachments())
    {
        mail.Attachmenets.Add(att);
    }
}
```

The downside of that is that we've now got an extra variable in scope, of course.

C# 7 is *likely* to address this problem with new features around pattern matching, so with the [current proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/206) you'd be able to write:

```
if (mailObject is Attachment attachment)
{
    // Use attachment
}
```

(As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend using braces even for single-statement `if` and `foreach` bodies. It makes it easier to read IMO, without having to rely on indentation always being perfect. I've seen far too many SO questions where coders have trusted the indentation and not noticed that their multiple statements aren't really related...)

Comment: `I've seen far too many SO questions where coders have trusted the indentation and not noticed that their multiple statements aren't really related...` I've never seen someone who's been programming for more than a month to have made such a mistake...

Comment: @Servy: I remember making such a mistake after a few years. Just once, but it was painful enough...

Comment: @JonSkeet Visual Studio IDE is so powerful nowadays to help out with stuff like that. If you build your solution it's all nicely pointed out on what lines there are errors, you'd have to be a bit slow to not notice errors like that ;)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: What makes you think it would be an error? It can be entirely valid code - just not the code that it looks like. I don't think it's coincidence that just about every code style guide I've ever seen for Java and C# says that braces should be used for all `if` statements and loops.

Comment: @JonSkeet For loops I agree actually, in 99% of the cases I use braces, for `if` `else` statements not so much, not using braces can sometimes drastically improve readability in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should have a read of Eric Lippert's discussions on the use of `is`. See http://ericlippert.com/2015/10/19/inferring-from-is/ & http://ericlippert.com/2015/10/22/inferring-from-is-part-two/.

Now, I thought it might be interesting to compare the two versions of the code and see what the difference is from an IL POV.

I started with this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); }
}
```

I then wrote these two programs:

(1)

```
object foo = new Foo();

if (foo is Foo)
    (foo as Foo).Hello();
```

(2)

```
object foo = new Foo();

Foo foo2 = foo as Foo;
if (foo2 != null)
    foo2.Hello();
```

The IL surprised me.

(1)

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // foo
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0008:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_000D:  ldnull      
IL_000E:  cgt.un      
IL_0010:  stloc.1     
IL_0011:  ldloc.1     
IL_0012:  brfalse.s   IL_0020
IL_0014:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0015:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_001A:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.Hello
IL_001F:  nop         
IL_0020:  ret
```

(2)

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // foo
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0008:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_000D:  stloc.1     // foo2
IL_000E:  ldloc.1     // foo2
IL_000F:  ldnull      
IL_0010:  cgt.un      
IL_0012:  stloc.2     
IL_0013:  ldloc.2     
IL_0014:  brfalse.s   IL_001D
IL_0016:  ldloc.1     // foo2
IL_0017:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.Hello
IL_001C:  nop         
IL_001D:  ret
```

There are actually more instructions for the (2) program. But the interesting thing is the `is` and `as` operators both call the same `isinst` instruction. The `is` operator then just does a comparison against `null`.

Now if I change the program to use the C# 6 `?.` feature it becomes this:

(3)

```
object foo = new Foo();

(foo as Foo)?.Hello();
```

The works as expected - `.Hello()` only gets called if `foo` is a `Foo` (I tested with a `Bar` type).

The IL is now this:

(3)

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // foo
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0008:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_000D:  dup         
IL_000E:  brtrue.s    IL_0013
IL_0010:  pop         
IL_0011:  br.s        IL_0019
IL_0013:  call        UserQuery+Foo.Hello
IL_0018:  nop         
IL_0019:  ret
```

This appears to be the shortest possible code, and probably most efficient. Timing would be the next thing to do as the only way to know which [horse is faster](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is to race them.

---

As per Eric's comment, I recompiled the code with optimization turned on and got this IL:

(1)

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // foo
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_0007:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_000C:  brfalse.s   IL_0019
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_000F:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_0014:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.Hello
IL_0019:  ret
```

(2)

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0005:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // foo2
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // foo2
IL_000C:  brfalse.s   IL_0014
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     // foo2
IL_000F:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.Hello
IL_0014:  ret
```

(3)

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0005:  isinst      UserQuery.Foo
IL_000A:  dup         
IL_000B:  brtrue.s    IL_000F
IL_000D:  pop         
IL_000E:  ret         
IL_000F:  call        UserQuery+Foo.Hello
IL_0014:  ret
```

Comment: I note that you're looking at the IL codegen with optimizations turned off. I don't know if it gets any better with them turned on, but you should not be surprised if the IL generated with the optimizer turned off is not optimal.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: Are you familiar with Java bytecode?  It's like that; an Intermediate Language that the jitter then turns into machine code. By having C#, VB, etc compile to IL, and then the jitters compile IL to x86, ARM, etc, you get the ability to have many compilers target many chipsets without writing a new code generator for each language.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out by the way. This article may also be of interest to you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is/

Comment: @EricLippert - Thanks for the comment. I've also posted the optimized IL.